# zipar itens selecionados para download único

Tags: php

Bom dia, tenho pesquisado porém não encontrei, então vamos lá.

tenho uma lista de itens ( documentos ) cadastrados no banco de dados e os seus respectivos arquivos em uma pasta, se eu preciso de um deles clico e faço o download deste, no entanto como fazer para fazer o download de vários ao selecionar com checkbox os que eu quero ? tipo:

```
$imp = implode(",",$_POST['arquivo']);
$arq = array ($imp);
$fileName  = 'zipFile.zip';
$path      = '../files';
$fullPath  = $path.'/'.$fileName;
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if( $zip->open($fullPath, \ZipArchive::CREATE) ){
    foreach($arq as $file){
        $zip->addFile($path.'/'.$file, $file);
    }
    $zip->close();
}
if(file_exists($fullPath)){
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
    readfile($fullPath);
    unlink($fullPath);
}
//echo $imp;
?>

depois de selecionados os que eu quero daria um submit
```

Comment: Sugiro uma olhada em https://github.com/TheNeoBurn/PHP_BjSZipper - Se não precisar da compactação de fato, só o "empacotamento" em um download único, essa é uma opção muito boa (ou ao menos é uma boa referência para você implementar algo similar). Esse projeto permite que você "zipe" o arquivo no envio, sem criar um arquivo real no seu filesystem ou na memória (os metadados são indexados, e o diretório é gerado em memória, mas o envio de fato é feito direto do que já existe no filesystem).

Answer (score -2):

consegui resolver, vou postar aqui para ajudar a quem precisar.

```
    $error = "";        
    if(isset($_POST['createzip'])){
        $file_folder = "../files/";    
        if(extension_loaded('zip')){    
            if(isset($_POST['arquivo']) and count($_POST['arquivo']) > 0){    
                $zip = new ZipArchive();            
                $zip_name = ($_POST['nomeid']).".zip";          
                if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){       
                    $error .=  "* erro 1<br/>";
                }
                foreach($_POST['arquivo'] as $file){               
                    $zip->addFile($file_folder.$file);          
                }
                $zip->close();
                if(file_exists($zip_name)){
                    
                    header('Content-type: application/zip');
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
                    readfile($zip_name);
                    
                    unlink($zip_name);
                }

            }else
                $error .= "* erro 2 <br/>";
        }else
            $error .= "* erro 3<br/>";
    }
?>
```